# Why didn't bada require scoped_ptr?

Tags: c++, bada

The bada C++ style guide/architecture uses a [two-step initialization](http://developer.bada.com/help/topic/com.osp.cppappprogramming.help/html/basics_bada_programming/two_phase_construction.htm) of C++ objects.

Why did they not simply require the use of scoped_ptr?

Comment: It should be called bad C++ style guide... Who in their right mind uses raw pointers that own something?

Comment: I wonder, was Bada invented by exiles from Symbian?

Comment: @Xeo: don't worry, they have clear [ownership policy](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppappprogramming.help/html/basics_bada_programming/obj_ownership_method_con.htm) that ought to solve the issue... *sigh*

Comment: @MatthieuM: suffixes on function names? It was *definitely* invented by exiles from Symbian!

Comment: [On the topic of two-phase initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471136/should-i-use-virtual-initialize-functions-to-initialize-an-object-of-my-clas).

Comment: I am noob here in c++ so I do not know general. But... do you guys "generally" think two-step initialization is worse than the original? I mean worse than developing android applications in Java or iPhone applciations in Object-C. Will bada be convenient to developers compare to android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ask them, because I am not a psychic.

However I suspect their answer will be the same as is written in bold near the top of that page: "Without two-phase construction, resource leak occurs".

I disagree with this assessment, though; the real problem is that their `ComplexClass` constructor body is not exception-safe. With that in place, the code will be *far more robust* with simple RAII, *especially as it scales*.

In terms of "why did they not simply require scoped_ptr": I'd imagine it's a C++03 document that's talking about C++, not third party libraries.

Comment: What I see you write is that there is no good technical reason against scoped_ptr, except it isn't C++03.  I see that it is not in C++11 either.  But C++11 has to have something like scoped_ptr, no?

Comment: @user239558: No, not that I can think of. As to why they didn't write about it, I don't see why you think we could tell you. Ask them! It's _their_ style guide.

Comment: @user239558: C++11 has `unique_ptr`, which is like `scoped_ptr` but movable.

Comment: @Tomalak: another weirdness in that document: in their "correct" code, they check the return value of `new` for null. But in their "incorrect" code, they claim that allocation failure can prevent the destructor of `ComplexClass` being called, which implies that they think an exception will be thrown out of `new` and hence out of the constructor. So either they have a non-standard `new` which is screwing up their coding style by requiring belt-and-braces checks, or else whoever wrote the style guide is terminally confused.

Answer (score 0):

The scoping is not the reason for the two-phase construction. The fact that constructors don't have any other way to return error than exception and they are not using exceptions are (IMHO the only reason is that they think it's still 10 years ago).